# How to fill up a drawable image

Tags: android

I have a .png image as seen below. I want to draw an inner circle inside the colorful ring so that it fills the white-space completely. Is there a way for me to calculate how large the radius of the inner circle should be without hard-coding values?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Considering the image dimensions, you can create a `layer-list` drawable  with `image` as background and circular item shape with desired color on top of that, something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/some"/>
    </item>
    <item android:top="45dp" android:bottom="45dp" android:left="45dp" android:right="45dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="250dp" />
            <solid android:color="#E02020" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This will produce output like below

[image]